# Google maps api for js maximum allowed waypoints error

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to draw a route along multiple waypoints on the map. But google responds with this error:

> Too many waypoints in the request (13). The maximum allowed waypoints
>   for this request is 8, plus the origin, and destination.

Currently I am using this url to load the google maps script:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&callback=initMap"></script>
```

According the google documentation it should be possible to use up to 23 wayponts each request if the api key is set in the url. [See here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/usage-limits)

What am I doing wrong? I've set the api key in the url and in my google console each request is shown as an successful request.

Also I've tried to run the app online and on localhost and also with a api key for browser and server. But nothing works so far.

Comment: Can you share a link to a sample which reproduces this or the error message you're getting when you try to use >8 waypoints?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps Directions API - Route not getting plotted for more than 8 waypoints](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34808063/google-maps-directions-api-route-not-getting-plotted-for-more-than-8-waypoints)

Comment: @bamnet, I've upload the script to this url: http://vweltje.nl/maps/
I hope you can help me.
(top right of the page is a button that should draw the route)